# What is the *formal* definition of separation in *binary* logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data, separation

I am trying to understand complete and quasi complete separation in the context of logistic binary regression. However, I have not found a clear source. I know the seminal paper

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2336390

but the definition is a bit hard to understand as it corresponds to multinomial logistic regression.

Could someone point me to a reference for these definitions on **binary** regression or to put them here in an answer?

Comment: Binary logistic regression is equivalent to multinomial logistic regression with 2 classes/groups. So, the paper you posted already gives the answer. Fig. 1 shows an example in the binary case. Might also be worth noting that linear separability is a geometric concept, not defined in terms of any probabilistic model (e.g logistic regression).